# Excel formula to compare two columns with colour and get the data of the column which has Amber colour

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns AA and AB columns which are filled with different colours, my formula should compare AA and AB column and find out which column have the Amber colour and display the value of that column in J column

I have tried to extract the value from AB and update it in the J column, but not able to compare AA and AB column with colour and based on that extract the value.

```
=INDEX($1:$1048576,I11,28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need VBA for this, so maybe an UDF would help you out (something quickly written):

```
Function AMBER(RNG1 As Range, RNG2 As Range) As String

If RNG1.Interior.Color = 48895 Then AMBER = RNG1.Value
If RNG2.Interior.Color = 48895 Then AMBER = RNG2.Value

End Function
```

Call in `J1` like:

```
=AMBER(AA1,AB1)
```

Drag down..

[image]

Comment: Thanks is there anyway to do this excel formula

Comment: No, I don't think so.